# Apache Rule not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create an `.htaccess` rule.

My link looks like below:

```
http://gpuzzles.com/brain-questions/funny-puzzles-and-riddles
```

This can be redirected to `gpuzzles.com/brain-questions/index.php`   (and i can get parameters as `funny-puzzles-and-riddles`)

I tried to create a new RewriteRule, but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^brain-questions/(.+)$ /brain-questions/index.php?var=$1
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a good description of your issue. What's the result? Does your server explode? @Clive He *is* redirecting to `/brain-questions/index.php`. Perhaps you meant "why are you redirecting"?

Comment: when i am calling url "http://gpuzzles.com/brain-questions/funny-puzzles-and-riddles"......... apache logs showing its not redirecting to anything

Comment: Did you try to use `[R]` after the rule to check whereto you're redirected?

Comment: logs showing
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2013:20:48:58 +0530] "GET /brain-questions/funny-puzzles-and-riddles1 HTTP/1.1" 404 240 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36

Comment: Shouldn't you include a `/` at the beginning of the rule? BTW, if I go to http://gpuzzles.com/brain-questions/funny-puzzles-and-riddles I don't get a 404.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel i m checking on development server :-)
adding / still not working

Comment: @SwatiMajumdar: What is location of this .htaccess? I mean in which directory you are placing it.

Comment: at docroot and now even at brain-questions

Comment: ok I posted an answer below. Make sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite is enabled when you try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in `/brain-questions/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /brain-questions/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm most likely you didn't use `RewriteBase`